# Restructure numpy array based on column and row list (Like pivot table in numpy array)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Here is the sample numpy datasource

```
     col    row1   row2   row3  row4  columns
[[(  11.2, '689', '197', 'value_2', 0, 1)]
 [(  56.4, '689', '197', 'value_3', 0, 1)]
 [(  195.7, '689', '197', 'value_2', 0, 2)]
 [(  565.2, '689', '197', 'value_3', 0, 2)]
 [(  227.6, '689', '197', 'value_2', 0, 3)]
 [(  1347.6, '689', '197', 'value_2', 0, 3)]
 [( 613.5, '689', '196', 'value_2', 0, 1)]
 [(139. , '689', '196', 'value_3', 0, 1)]
 [( 6011. , '689', '196', 'value_2', 0, 2)]
 [(103. , '689', '196', 'value_3', 0, 2)]
 [( 6860. , '689', '196', 'value_2', 0, 3)]
 [(1302. , '689', '196', 'value_3', 0, 3)]
 [( 1787.9, '622', '197', 'value_2', 0, 1)]
 [( 632.5, '622', '197', 'value_3', 0, 1)]
 [( 178.8, '622', '197', 'value_2', 0, 2)]
 [( 6360.5, '622', '197', 'value_3', 0, 2)]
 [( 228. , '622', '196', 'value_2', 0, 1)]
 [(672. , '622', '196', 'value_3', 0, 2)]
 ]
```

So from this expected output should be

```
                                   1       2       3

row1   row2    row3        row4
689    197     value_2     0       11.2    195.7   227.6
689    197     value_3     0       56.4    565     1347
689    196     value_2     0       613.5   6011    6860
689    196     value_3     0       139     103     1302
622    197     value_2     0       1787    178     
622    197     value_3     0       632     6360
```

Above 1 2 3 columns are getting from one column in numpy array, that is rank

From the data given, the row1 will always be 1 but it has multiple row2, row3 and row4.
For every data in row1 should find equivalent rows and populate as mentioned in the output.

I have tried the below code, but unable to get the (1, 2, 3) column values properly, as it is in different place I couldn't take and write in numpy array.

```
new_temp_arr = 'actual_data_given'
m = 1
row_list = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4']
# Column list taken from the array based on rank column
column_list = [1, 2, 3]
sample_list = []

for value in new_temp_arr:
    for new_value in new_temp_arr:
        if m >= len(new_temp_arr):
            break
        new_value = new_temp_arr[m]
        # Checking all the values for the rows matches with one another
        condition = [value[row] == new_value[row] for row in row_list]
        if all(condition):
            # Looping through all the column list and getting the float value
            # I'm stuck here, how to store the values with properly matched data
            for per in column_list:
                if new_value['rank'] == [per]:
                    float_value = new_value['float_value']
                    sample_list.append(new_value)
        m += 1
```

Comment: The nature of 'sample numpy datasource' is unclear.  Column headers aren't part of an array.  The nesting of `[]` and `()` suggest it is a structured array, but you haven't provided either shape or dtype.  But it could be object dtype, or simply lists of tuples.  I don't think `numpy` will help here.  For grouping operations I like to use `dict`, or even `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: Yeah it's a structured arrays, dtype I mentioned as col rows etc.. Thanks for the input I try with defaultdict

Comment: Do you know the full set of unique `row#` values before hand?

Comment: Unique row, means, what are you asking about exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_list(arr, row1, row_column_values, row_list, column_list, index):
    dict_keys = {i: [] for i in column_list}
    dic = {row1: dict_keys}
    for value in arr:
        if index == len(arr):
            index = 0
        value = arr[index]
        condition = [value[row][0] == row_column_values[row] for row in row_list]
        if all(condition):
            dic[row1][int(value['rank'][0])] = value['float_value'][0]
            if index == 0:
                break
        index += 1
        
        
new_temp_arr = 'actual_data_given'
m = 1
row_list = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4']
# Column list taken from the array based on rank column
column_list = [1, 2, 3]
out_array = np.zeros() #Numpy array with type
dic = {}
    
for value in new_temp_arr:
    row_values = {row: value[row][0] for row in row_list}
    dic = get_list(new_temp_arr, value['row1'][0], row_values, row_list, column_list, m)
    float_value = list(dic[value['row1'][0]].values())
    out_array[out_index] = tuple(list(value[row_list][0]) + float_value)

return out_array
```

The above code gets the expected result as I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this efficiently with `numpy`, especially since you have duplicates in your data and a simple pivot would fail (it seems you're keeping the first value, although not entirely sure, please clarify this point).

Furthermore, it looks like your output is a dataframe, so why not use `pandas` directly with `pivot_table` and `aggfunc='first'`?:

```
a = np.array([[(  11.2, '689', '197', 'value_2', 0, 1)],
              [(  56.4, '689', '197', 'value_3', 0, 1)],
              [(  195.7, '689', '197', 'value_2', 0, 2)],
              [(  565.2, '689', '197', 'value_3', 0, 2)],
              [(  227.6, '689', '197', 'value_2', 0, 3)],
              [(  1347.6, '689', '197', 'value_2', 0, 3)],
              [( 613.5, '689', '196', 'value_2', 0, 1)],
              [(139. , '689', '196', 'value_3', 0, 1)],
              [( 6011. , '689', '196', 'value_2', 0, 2)],
              [(103. , '689', '196', 'value_3', 0, 2)],
              [( 6860. , '689', '196', 'value_2', 0, 3)],
              [(1302. , '689', '196', 'value_3', 0, 3)],
              [( 1787.9, '622', '197', 'value_2', 0, 1)],
              [( 632.5, '622', '197', 'value_3', 0, 1)],
              [( 178.8, '622', '197', 'value_2', 0, 2)],
              [( 6360.5, '622', '197', 'value_3', 0, 2)],
              [( 228. , '622', '196', 'value_2', 0, 1)],
              [(672. , '622', '196', 'value_3', 0, 2)],
             ])
cols = ['col', 'row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4', 'columns']
(pd.DataFrame(a[:,0,:], columns=cols)
   .pivot_table(index=['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4'], columns='columns', values='col', aggfunc='first')
)
```

output:

```
columns                      1       2       3
row1 row2 row3    row4                        
622  196  value_2 0      228.0     NaN     NaN
          value_3 0        NaN   672.0     NaN
     197  value_2 0     1787.9   178.8     NaN
          value_3 0      632.5  6360.5     NaN
689  196  value_2 0      613.5  6011.0  6860.0
          value_3 0      139.0   103.0  1302.0
     197  value_2 0       11.2   195.7   227.6
          value_3 0       56.4   565.2     NaN
```

If the order is important you can `reindex` to the original order:

```
cols = ['col', 'row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4', 'columns']
df = pd.DataFrame(a[:,0,:], columns=cols)

idx = df.set_index(['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4']).index
idx = idx[~idx.duplicated(keep='first')]

(df.pivot_table(index=['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4'], columns='columns', values='col', aggfunc='first')
   .reindex(idx)
)
```

output:

```
columns                      1       2       3
row1 row2 row3    row4                        
689  197  value_2 0       11.2   195.7   227.6
          value_3 0       56.4   565.2     NaN
     196  value_2 0      613.5  6011.0  6860.0
          value_3 0      139.0   103.0  1302.0
622  197  value_2 0     1787.9   178.8     NaN
          value_3 0      632.5  6360.5     NaN
     196  value_2 0      228.0     NaN     NaN
          value_3 0        NaN   672.0     NaN
```

Comment: I have to use only numpy, that's the requirement.  Order is not an issue. Any value can come first and last that will not be the problem. I just need to extract this structure with numpy.